# NestJs unit testing error: TypeError: this.x is not a function

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have a small issue with a unit test I wrote for a controller method.

**Short version:**

```
return this.userPreferencesService.createPreferences(eUserId, userPreferences);
```

**Long version:**

I get this error:

```
UserPreferencesController › createUserPreferences › should create a new userPreferences
 TypeError: this.userPreferencesService.createPreferences is not a function

      31 |             userPreferences: TestUserPreferencesDto,
      32 |     ): Promise<UserPreferences> {
    > 33 |         return this.userPreferencesService.createPreferences(eUserId, userPreferences);
         |                                            ^
      34 |     }
      35 |
      36 |     /**

      at UserPreferencesController.createPreferences (user-preferences/user-preferences.controller.ts:33:44)
      at Object.<anonymous> (user-preferences/user-preferences.controller.spec.ts:67:45)
```

The `toBeDefined` passes but the `createUserPreferences` fails for the error above.
The code works great and there only the test fails.
I just can't find the reason this is not a function?

service file content (relevant data only):

```
@Injectable()
export class UserPreferencesService {

    constructor(@InjectModel('UserPreferences') private userPreferencesModel: Model<UserPreferences>) {
    }

   

    /**
     * ADD a single user preferences by id => POST api/v1/user-preferences/
     * @param userPreferences
     */
    async createPreferences(eUserId: string, userPreferences: TestUserPreferencesDto): Promise<UserPreferences> {

        Object.assign(userPreferences, {eUserId: eUserId});
        return this.userPreferencesModel.create(userPreferences);
    }
```

This is the controller (relevant data only)

```
@Controller('v1/user-preferences')
export class UserPreferencesController {

    constructor(private userPreferencesService: UserPreferencesService) {}

    /**
     * Add user preferences to the database
     * @param userPreferences
     */
    @Post()
    async createPreferences(
        @Headers('x-e-user-id') eUserId: string,
        @Body()
            userPreferences: TestUserPreferencesDto,
    ): Promise<UserPreferences> {
        return this.userPreferencesService.createPreferences(eUserId, userPreferences);
    }
```

This is the entire test file:

```
import {Test, TestingModule} from '@nestjs/testing';
import { getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import {UserPreferencesController} from './user-preferences.controller';
import {UserPreferencesService} from './user-preferences.service';
import { exitToOptions } from './schemas/user-preferences.schema';

const ReturnedUserPreferencesMock = {
    _id: '62a161a9654a511b28e6f3db',
    eUserId: '123456',
    uiTheme: 'dark',
    panelWidth: 300,
    editingHandles: true,
    enableLightboxInEditor: true,
    hiddenElements: true,
    defaultDeviceView: 'mobile',
    exitTo: exitToOptions.DASHBOARD,
};

const eUserIdeMock = '123456';

const userPreferencesMock = {
    uiTheme: 'dark',
    panelWidth: 327,
    editingHandles: true,
    enableLightboxInEditor: true,
    hiddenElements: true,
    defaultDeviceView: 'mobile',
    exitTo: exitToOptions.DASHBOARD,
}


const mockUserPreferencesService = {
    create: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(ReturnedUserPreferencesMock),
}


describe('UserPreferencesController', () => {

    let controller: UserPreferencesController;
    let service: UserPreferencesService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            controllers: [UserPreferencesController],
            providers: [{
                provide: UserPreferencesService,
                useValue: mockUserPreferencesService
            }]
        }).compile();

        controller = module.get<UserPreferencesController>(UserPreferencesController);
        service = module.get<UserPreferencesService>(UserPreferencesService);
    });

    it('Controler should be defined', () => {
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });

    describe('createUserPreferences', () => {
        it('should create a new userPreferences', async () => {
            const result = await controller.createPreferences(eUserIdeMock, userPreferencesMock);
            expect(service.createPreferences).toHaveBeenCalledWith(eUserIdeMock, userPreferencesMock);
            expect(result).toEqual(ReturnedUserPreferencesMock);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and inspect `this.userPreferencesService`, or add `console.log` for the same if not using a debugger.

Comment: In the test file? AHH, in the service file

Comment: On the line that’s failing

Comment: I addded console.log before the falling line. 

`console.log("this.userPreferencesService: ", this.userPreferencesService);
        return this.userPreferencesService.getPreferences(eUserId);`


This is what I see:


`this.userPreferencesService:  UserPreferencesService {
  userPreferencesModel: Model { UserPreferences }
}
`
I see that the service does not exist, but I am able to pass data through the service as I  can crud data to the DB

Comment: That seems to suggest that `this.userPreferencesService` is an instance of `UserPreferencesService`, and has a property `userPreferencesModel`.  It seems odd that an instance of `UserPreferencesService` does not have the `createPreferences` function, but there appears to be some dependency injection going on (I'm not familiar with NestJS itself) and can only assume that this is not setup correctly for the test environment if the code works in the production env.

Answer (score 0):

The `mockUserPreferencesService` you provide does not have a `createPreferences` method, only a `create`. You need to provide an implementation for each method you are going to call of the original service for your mock.

```js
const mockUserPreferencesService = {
    create: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(ReturnedUserPreferencesMock),
    createPreferences: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(WhateverObjectShouldGoHere),
}
```